# Weird sdl opengl linker

Tags: opengl, linker, compiler-errors, sdl

Heres one of the errors:

```
unresolved external symbol _SDL_SetVideoMode referenced in function _SDL_main
```

This is being linked:

```
sdl.lib
sdlmain.lib
glu32.lib
opengl32.lib
```

Im calling both `sdl` and `sdl_opengl`

Comment: Which compiler toolchain do you use?

Comment: Im using VC++ 2012 and the project is in win32. if that was what you were asking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order does matter when linking sometimes. Link to sdlmain first and then sdl and see if that works.